# Is it possible for a living being to be made up of dark matter, neutrinos or similar other particles that don't interact with regular matter?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

What I have in mind is a species of creature that are made up of particles that do not interact with base matter, though unlike true dark matter they can interact with themselves. Would this be theoretically possible? What is the likelihood of such life arising? If so, how would such a creature *work* in terms of anatomy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It all depends on what meaning you assign to the word *life*. The usual understanding of a living organism requires the ability to extract energy from the environment, to assimilate matter from the environment in order to grow and reproduce, and to respond to environmental stimuli. A creature made of particles which do not interact with ordinary matter can be considered alive if it exists in an environment where such particles are sufficiently common in order to enable it to carry out the basic functions of life based only on interactions with particles it can interact with.

Comment: If they're not actually made of dark matter they can have whatever properties you want. We can't tell you how a sci fi particle you invented works.

Comment: Hello Alden, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Per the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build the rules of an imaginary world. You can have anything you want in your world. Thus, the answers to Qs like this are usually always "yes," except that you used the [tag:science-based] tag. In this case, the answer is "no," because all such particles are theoretical, meaning we have no empirical evidence they exist, and therefore have no way to guess their potential for life. Is it necessary for your fictional creature to have a Real World scientific basis built on what, today, is fictional matter?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a quantum mathematician to figure out a new theory of everything. People have made their entire careers from trying to answer this question, so you're probably not going to get an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.

*Definately not with neutrinos.* They do not interact with each other in any practical way as would be required to form anything with structure (surely a prerequisite for a living being).

*Almost certainly not with dark matter*. The properties required for dark matter, as used to explain astromomical measurements such as the anomolous rotation of galaxies, gravitational lensing etc. are such that not only does dark matter not interact with matter but it also doesn't interact with other dark matter particles except via gravity. So all you are likely to get is a diffuse and nebulous 'gas' of dark matter - once again with no structure or intermal interaction that could result in a living being.

Comment: I disagree. While they might not work for explaining the shape of galaxy arms, there is nothing to prevent the author inventing "dark charge"-d particles which interact with other "dark charge"-d particles.

Comment: @Daron In that case your not using Dark Matter as its understood in the real world and all the real world implications it would have. Your just creating your own Shadow universe and borrowing the term.

Comment: @Daron in principle, no, but such properties have to be artificial or at least very rare in nature, because dark matter only has the properties needed to fit observation if it only self-interacts gravitationally. If it's clumping up and forming dark solar systems, it's not forming the diffuse halos of excess mass that we observe.

Comment: @Shadowzee That is true. However inventing new dark particles  is consistent with the question talking about "unlike true dark matter" and things being "theoretically possible."

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff As I say  it would not be the same stuff that is suspected to cloud around the edges of galaxies.

Answer (score 1):

**Sure**

No one knows what dark matter is. Know one knows whether dark mater exists or not. Certainly no one has a flask of dark matter in a lab somewhere.

That means you can make up your own rules.

"Dark Matter" is a proposed explanation for why galaxies are shaped the way they are. Some scientists think the galaxy is much bigger than it looks, but the cloud of stuff on the outside is invisible. Meaning it does not react to light or electricity. So we can only see it by measuring its gravity.

If this is true, then dark matter would pass right through regular matter. Regular matter is mostly empty space you see. The reason you cannot walk through the wall is because the electrons on the outside of the wall repel the electrons on the outside of your body.

No one knows what the dark extra stuff is made of. So you are free to say it is made of whatever you like. You could have a whole dark-matter universe existing under the real one. Dark matter protons, electrons, plants and animals. The dark electrons repel each other but ignore the normal electrons. If you had a whole dark matter star, normal planets might orbit the dark matter star. This is because it still has gravity. But it would not light up the sky of the planet.

Comment: "But it would not light up the sky of the planet.": not with electromagnetic light, anyway.

Comment: The webcomic Schlock Mercenary did something like this, with the big antagonists being a dark matter civilization. Notably though, the dark matter life used artificial metastable dark matter analogues of normal matter (created by ancient civilizations because it was useful to be able to build things out of the other 90% of the matter in the universe) that would support dark matter chemistry complex enough to form life.